# Manga where MC gets summoned to another world by a female god in order to kill an evil god

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I'm looking for manga where MC is playing a VR game but gets summoned to another world by a female god in order to kill an evil god. During the first chapter he kills a frog as soon as he is summoned into the other world in order to have supplies. After that he builds a house in order to not have many predators after him.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this ***[The Strongest in Another World with Assassination Skills - I, Who Has Mastered Alchemy and Assassination, Dominate the World from Behind](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/88gruop/ansatsu-skill-de-isekai-saikyou-renkinjutsu-to-ansatsujutsu-o-kiwameta-ore-wa-sekai-o-kage-kara-shihai-suru)***...?

> Late has just accepted an assassination from a strange, mysterious client. To his surprise, it was actually the goddess Mises. A goddess from another world whose exsistence was on the brink of destruction after her defeat in war. Mises' quest… is to assassinate Masura Dzur, another god in her world. Late, the assassin with a 99.9% success rate, was tasked to assassinate a god in another world?!

As per the summary above, the main character is summoned to another world by a goddess and tasked with assassinating another god.

He also builds a house in a forest and kills a frog-like monster in the first chapter.

[image: "Wheew... done!" he says, standing in front of a cabin]

[image: "A frog. Is it a monster? I hope it's edible" he says, aiming his bow at the frog]

Comment: Yes, this is the one thanks you for finding it for me.